# My RAV4 scissor jack head is curved, did I just misposition it?

Tags: toyota, rav4, jack

I used my scissor jack that came with the car to change the 4 winter tires on my car to 4 summer tires. The car is Toyota RAV4, and after the change, a part of the head of the scissor jack is curved.

Did I just misposition the jack which caused the metal in the head of the jack to bend? I'm worried that the scissor jack might not be durable anymore in a bent state, and since everyone warns not to use the scissor jack for seasonal tire change (apparently, floor jacks are better, although I have my doubts about cheap floor jacks), I have considered purchasing a new scissor jack, and inspecting the car for possible damages in case I mispositioned it. I don't remember if the jack head was curved in this manner when it was new. Should I purchase a new scissor jack and inspect the car for possible damages?

Answer (score 1):

A part of the head of the RAV4 jack that comes with the car apparently is curved already when it comes from the factory, at least according to a Google image search. So, chances are the jack and more importantly your car is as good as new, although you should of course investigate and lubricate the scissor jack well if using it often.

Examples from Google image search (search terms were rav4 jack, the links probably die eventually and for copyright reasons the images can't be copied elsewhere, only linked to, so in case the images stop working, just do a new google image search):

[image]

[image]

[image]